# How to loop through NSDictionary to get specific values

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary that looks like this.

```
{
groups =     (
            {
        color = "<null>";
        createdBy = System;
        groupName = "Best friends";
        groupType = regular;
        id = 583562ede4b030a2a979dfa3;
        lastModifiedOn = "<null>";
        maxNoOfMembersAllowed = 9;
        members = "<null>";
        pictureLastModifiedOn = "<null>";
        position = 1;
        searchCriteria = "<null>";
        status = Active;
    },
            {
        color = "<null>";
        createdBy = System;
        groupName = Family;
        groupType = regular;
        id = 583562ede4b030a2a979dfa6;
        lastModifiedOn = "<null>";
        maxNoOfMembersAllowed = 9;
        members = "<null>";
        pictureLastModifiedOn = "<null>";
        position = 2;
        searchCriteria = "<null>";
        status = Active;
    },
            {
        color = "<null>";
        createdBy = System;
        groupName = Work;
        groupType = regular;
        id = 583562ede4b030a2a979dfa9;
        lastModifiedOn = "<null>";
        maxNoOfMembersAllowed = 9;
        members = "<null>";
        pictureLastModifiedOn = "<null>";
        position = 3;
        searchCriteria = "<null>";
        status = Active;
    }
);
status = Success;
statusText = "Group:Get Successful."; 
}
```

I'd like to get all groupName values, let's just say just I'd like to print them in the console for now.

How do I iterate through this NSDictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `dictionary` is the root object this code prints all `groupName` strings

```
if let groups = dictionary["groups"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    for group in groups {
       print(group["groupName"] as! String)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More Swifty

```
let groups = [["groupName" : "a"], ["groupName" : "b"]]

let groupNames = groups.map { (elem) -> String in
    return elem["groupName"]!
}

print(groupNames) //returns ["a", "b"]
```